# How to test disabling automatic backups on ios and android?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, testing, backup

I am building an app with Ionic v1, Cordova, and AngularJS v 1.5.

I am targeting both Android and iOS.

I have been advised to turn off automatic backups for security reasons.

I believe this applies to both iOS and Android. iCloud and Google Cloud.

Our app has already been in use for quite some time so some people will have backups already.

If I disable backups, will the people's backups still be there? From the past? And then it will no longer backup anymore? If there any way to get rid of the previous backups from the app? Can we do anything about the past?

Furthermore, I will need to test if disabling this will actually work and not do any backups. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable auto backup on Android by going into your **manifest** file and changing `android:allowBackup="true"` to `android:allowBackup="false"`.

> Auto Backup for Apps automatically backs up a user's data from apps that target and run on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or later

Example:

```
<manifest ... >
...
<application android:allowBackup="false" ... > <!-- This will opt out of auto backups -->
    ...
</application>
```

You can read more about [auto backups.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup)

**Backup location**

> Backup data is stored in a private folder in the user's Google Drive account, limited to 25MB per app. The saved data does not count towards the user's personal Google Drive quota

To confirm if it is backed up.

> Users can see a list of apps that have been backed up in the Google Drive Android app. On an Android-powered device, users can find this list in the Drive app's navigation drawer under Settings > Backup and reset > App data.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know about what happens to the past backups and how to test this change?

Comment: Past backups are auto-deleted after a period of inactivity. The period is of 2 weeks. If you read the updated post, I quoted from the page on how to test it.

Comment: Thank you! Do you also know how to do this on iOS?

Comment: No, only Android.